# gnome-software does not launch

Tags: 20.04, xfce, system-monitor, gnome-software

I'm getting this error message if I'm running Gnome Software Center from terminal.

`Failed to setup plugins: Unable to find default local file monitor type`

Dropbox is also giving me a similar error message and it doesn't sync.

My OS is Xubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Since then I noticed that there is a difference between Xubuntu and XFCE sessions. I'm not really sure why both exist on my system. In any case these problems don't come up if I'm launching a Xubuntu session, only if I'm in an XFCE session.